# how does the gsub() function help in replacing retweet entries in sentiment analysis in R

Tags: r, twitter, gsub, sentiment-analysis

Tgus code shows how to remove Retweet option from tweets in case of sentiment analysis in R.

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("iPhone", n=1500, lang="en")
txt <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText())
txt <- gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", txt)
```

What I don't understand is that in the `gsub ()` function, where does the pattern

```
(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)
```

come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down:

`(RT|via)` - Match "RT" or "via"

Everything else is a non-capturing group defined by `(?:)`, meaning we check that it exists, but we don't capture it.

`(?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)`

`\\b` is a word boundary

`\\W*` is a non-word character. `*` means match 0 or more

Match a `@`

`\\w+` and one or more word characters (letter, digit, connector)

`+` outside of the non-capturing group means there can be more than one of these non-capturing groups.

Basically you're matching "via" or "RT" and removing it (via the "" blank you're replacing the captured text with), and matching but not capturing everything else that follows

The non-capturing group is used so you can match "RT" or "via" in varying positions in the string. `\\b\\W*@\\w+` is making sure you match a twitter username after the "RT" or "via". This should help avoid replacing "RT" or "via" when it's not used as an actual re-tweet.

Comment: That was a very elaboarte and an apt answer to the question, thankyou@Mako212. Thankyou for the effort!  Could you share the possible links/resources that helped you with the information?

Comment: @KrishnaDhruv Sure, [Rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) is a fantastic resource for Regex. I found it very helpful in learning the basics, and all the key expressions are conveniently organized in tables for reference.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again :)

Comment: @KrishnaDhruv Since it appears this solved your problem, you should accept it as the best answer with the check mark!

Comment: yep I did that :)